# Run a program headless with virtual display and control it using pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui, headless

Is it possible to for example run word headless and the control it using pyautogui and this all headless with a virtual display? It needs to work on windows 10, because the program I want to run is a .exe and doesnt work with wine.

Comment: Yes. Please clarify your question if you want another answer, take the time to learn [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), show what you have achieved so far and what problems are you encountering.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.